# is there any way to restrict API access to Telegram private group?

Tags: telegram, telethon

i have a private group which users join using a link. i don't want to allow any user that has the group link to access it with Telegram API/ telethon. can i restrict API access to my group?

Comment: All Clients (i.e. the Android and iOS Apps and Telegram Desktop) use the Telegram API so that wouldn't make sense

Comment: Thanks @SitiSchu for the comment. Deos telegram provide any way to whitelist/blacklist telegram applications created by community (i.e. Block all but telegram official apps you mentioned)

Comment: Nope, that's not a thing either on afraid, and besides, it could be easily circumvented by using the API id and hash of the official clients